# Flutter setState of child widget without rebuilding parent

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I have a parent that contain a `listView` and a `floatingActionButton` i would like to hide the `floatingActionButton` when the user starts scrolling i have managed to do this within the parent widget but this requires the list to be rebuilt each time.

I have moved the `floatingActionButton` to a separate class so i can update the state and only rebuild that widget the problem i am having is passing the data from the `ScrollController` in the parent class to the child this is simple when doing it through navigation but seams a but more awkward without rebuilding the parent!

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: You could use a GlobalKey for the FAB, then use that to access the FAB from the ScrollController. This is a pattern that is not encouraged, but might fit your needs. A more architecturally sound approach would be to use something like Flutter Redux (https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_redux
) for responding to actions.

Comment: OP, are you sure that `setState` is actually causing a performance problem? The fab only disappears/reappears once in a while. Flutter is optimized for this kind of stuff. Widgets are really lightweight, the underlying heavy UI objects are NOT disposed/rebuilt when you call `setState`.

Comment: @boformer I was under the impression that setState purpose was to rebuild the UI that there has been a change https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html but to answer the question no I cannot be sure I am just learning flutter and it look like it dose things a bit different that what I expect, should or can I request a rebuild from the parent?
I did notice when i was doing a live reload the state would sometime change if i had scrolled down the page prior to the live reload!

Comment: @DerekLakin thanks for the suggestions they are appreciated but I would like to do things the flutter way and for a "simple" task i think redux would make it more complex than it need to be, GlobalKey may be a temporary option.

Comment: I'm not sure where you are coming from, but triggering a rebuild, even of a larger part of the page, is not unusual. 

In normal use cases (things which do not change more than 5 times per second), calling `setState` on the parent is the way to go.

If rebuilding is too slow, look at my answer below. Flutter will not rebuild widgets which are exactly the same instance.

Calling `setState` of a child from a parent is NOT the way to go. `GlobalKey` was not made for that. The parent should never access the child.

Comment: the problem with the rebuild was that its slow so due to the it taking a long time to rebuild it would not have been worth hiding the button and looking at some of the google tutorials they say about not rebuilding elements that don't need rebuilding like the parent nothing changed in the list but it was still being rebuilt I am not 100% sure but this may have been because it was being built from firestore! maybe I should save a local copy of the list a compare it... anyway I have accepted you answer below thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61142775/flutter-setstate-inside-listview-builders-builditem-function-not-reloading/61151798#61151798

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For optimal performance, you can create your own wrapper around `Scaffold` that gets the `body` as a parameter. The `body` widget will not be rebuilt when `setState` is called in `HideFabOnScrollScaffoldState`.

This is a common pattern that can also be found in core widgets such as `AnimationBuilder`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyHomePage()));

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MyHomePageState();
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  ScrollController controller = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return HideFabOnScrollScaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        controller: controller,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) => ListTile(title: Text('item $i')),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      controller: controller,
    );
  }
}

class HideFabOnScrollScaffold extends StatefulWidget {
  const HideFabOnScrollScaffold({
    Key key,
    this.body,
    this.floatingActionButton,
    this.controller,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Widget body;
  final Widget floatingActionButton;
  final ScrollController controller;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => HideFabOnScrollScaffoldState();
}

class HideFabOnScrollScaffoldState extends State<HideFabOnScrollScaffold> {
  bool _fabVisible = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.controller.addListener(_updateFabVisible);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.controller.removeListener(_updateFabVisible);
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _updateFabVisible() {
    final newFabVisible = (widget.controller.offset == 0.0);
    if (_fabVisible != newFabVisible) {
      setState(() {
        _fabVisible = newFabVisible;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: widget.body,
      floatingActionButton: _fabVisible ? widget.floatingActionButton : null,
    );
  }
}
```

Alternatively you could also create a wrapper for `FloatingActionButton`, but that will probably break the transition.

Comment: thank you this is what I was looking for it works perfect without rebuilding the list each time.
this line dose need editing though from == to !=
`code`
  void _updateFabVisible() {
    final newFabVisible = (widget.controller.offset == 0.0);
    if (_fabVisible != newFabVisible) {
      setState(() {
        _fabVisible = newFabVisible;
      });
    }
  }
`code`

Comment: how to detect when the offset exactly = 50 ? The scroll offset sometime skip the offset when scrolled too fast

Answer (score 36):

A nice way to rebuild **only a child** widget when a value in the parent changes is to use [ValueNotifier](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ValueNotifier-class.html) and [ValueListenableBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ValueListenableBuilder-class.html). Add an instance of `ValueNotifier` to the parent's state class, and wrap the widget you want to rebuild in a `ValueListenableBuilder`.

When you want to change the value, do so using the notifier **without calling `setState`** and the child widget rebuilds using the new value.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Parent extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ParentState createState() => _ParentState();
}

class _ParentState extends State<Parent> {
  ValueNotifier<bool> _notifier = ValueNotifier(false);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => _notifier.value = !_notifier.value, child: Text('toggle')),
        ValueListenableBuilder(
            valueListenable: _notifier,
            builder: (BuildContext context, bool val, Widget? child) {
              return Text(val.toString());
            }),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
      _notifier.dispose();

      super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: This should be new accepted answer. It is exactly what is needed.

Comment: With only several lines of code. this is great.

Comment: +1. Just note that it DOES internally call the setState(). You might face the error of this internal setState while a redrawing is under way.

Comment: this is perfect. I tried looking into Bloc providers, Stream builders, even just messy manually invoked callbacks to setState(), but using ValueListener as a wrapper is the perfect balance for simple rebuilds of child widgets. thank you for this, i wish i had found this right away.

Answer (score 12):

I think using a stream is more simpler and also pretty easy.

You just need to post to the stream when your event arrives and then use a stream builder to respond to those changes.

Here I am showing/hiding a component based on the focus of a widget in the widget hierarchy.

I've used the rxdart package here but I don't believe you need to. also you may want to anyway because most people will be using the BloC pattern anyway.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class _PageState extends State<Page> {
  final _focusNode = FocusNode();

  final _focusStreamSubject = PublishSubject<bool>();
  Stream<bool> get _focusStream => _focusStreamSubject.stream;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _focusNode.addListener(() {
      _focusStreamSubject.add(_focusNode.hasFocus);
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          _buildVeryLargeComponent(),
          StreamBuilder(
            stream: _focusStream,
            builder: ((context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data) {
                return Text("keyboard has focus")
              }
              return Container();
            }),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I was struggling to understand stream builder. your answer is very simple and easy to understand. many thanks.

Comment: Your code has many errors and is not complete, however your idea is good

Comment: @MohsenEmami Please elaborate. Do you mean that the _buildVeryLargeComponent function is not declared? Or that the component is omitted for brevity? This is a very normal stateful component.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [StatefulBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html) and use its setState function to build widgets under it.

Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {

  int count = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        // put widget here that you do not want to update using _setState of StatefulBuilder
        Container(
          child: Text("I am static"),
        ),
        StatefulBuilder(builder: (_context, _setState) {
          // put widges here that you want to update using _setState
          return Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                child: Text("I am updated for $count times"),
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('Update'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    // Following only updates widgets under StatefulBuilder as we are using _setState
                    // that belong to StatefulBuilder
                    _setState(() {
                      count++;
                    });
                  })
            ],
          );
        }),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How will I call child's setState from outside StatefulBuilder

Comment: @NullByte08 You could try by assigning _setState to a global variable. However, that might not be a correct approach. Consider using Stream. Look at David Rees's answer for that.