# Do adding, removing a child to stack cause all stack children to rebuild?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Let's say I have a stack of 100 positioned widget children, I add one new positioned widget to that stack but the rest don't change, then I setState to rebuild that stack, should all 100 children run their rebuild function? I ask because this is happening in my app but was hoping I could prevent the rebuild of the entire stack, since flutter should see most of the stack as unchanged.

edit: [more accurately, how do i make sure i'm not re-rendering all 100 widgets in the stack when i add one child or remove one child, is there a way to verify, inspect the render tree]

Comment: yes, all of them should rebuild

Comment: is there a way to isolate the 100 by wrapping them somehow, or other solution

Comment: btw what are those 100 widgets? are they typical widgets like buttons, text fields, sliders etc or you are trying to use some widgets in a hacky way?

Comment: they're draggable widgets that can be moved around the screen that have a variety of widget trees with text , images, CustomPainter paths.

Comment: they have positions so they can stay in that position after dragging. as you can imagine i don't want all of them to refresh if i just add one or remove one.

Answer (score 1):

All the widgets inside a stateful widget should be rebuild in every setState,
To prevent of setState some widgets you should have a separate stateful widget for the stack.
[this may useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51725031/flutter-setstate-of-child-widget-without-rebuilding-parent)